# How to debug problems with GWT dev/hosted mode?

Tags: java, debugging, gwt, maven

I'm trying to set up the GWT dev/hosted mode in a Maven-based Java webapp. I start my webapp via Maven Tomcat7 plugin (mvn tomcat7:run-war-only) and it is running fine. Also, startup of GWT via mvn gwt:run works and shows no errors.

However, if I access my webapp with the gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 parameter, I just see a blank page in my browser. Interestingly, the page source contains the content of my JSP, but it is only defining some divs to be replaced by GWT.

How do I debug this situation? I haven't found any option for GWT dev mode to generate some kind of logging output. For example, it would be interesting to know if the GWT code server ever receives a call. At the moment, I'm missing any clue where to start looking why GWT dev mode is not working.

Comment: Did you compile your client code first?

Comment: Sure, I first do mvn clean install, start it afterwards in my server with mvn tomcat7:run-war-only, verify in browser that it works, and finally append the gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 parameter resulting in a blank page. I added a Window.alert() directly at the beginning of my onModuleLoad() function and this alert isn't shown in case the code server parameter is present.

Comment: And when did you start the Development mode module?

Comment: As said before, I usually start it after Tomcat initialized completely. But I also tried first starting GWT dev mode.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? If so, check the Development mode view for errors

Comment: @Sebi: any error in your browser's dev console? How about network accesses? Is there a request to `devmode.js` or `hosted.html` and is it successful?

Comment: I'm just using pure Maven based project. If Dev Mode works via Maven, I will try to get it working in an IDE, but at the moment I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer I got it working! It seems to be a set of problems, but with a few manual steps it works now. First, I increased log output by putting <logLevel>WARN into gwt maven configuration section. Second, I must ensure that I don't access the page directly. Instead, first access must go through GWT codeserver. If not, I have to delete a few files in my exloded war and force refresh the page in my browser. Ok, now I need to figure out how to set it up in my IDE :-)

Comment: @Sebi note `logLevel` defaults to INFO, so WARN is actually *decreasing* it. Also maybe have a look at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Sorry, yes, that's what I meant. I actually changed it to ALL :-) I also created a small example to better debug modular GWT projects with maven, see: https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original question was, how to debug Maven GWT plugin in case it is not doing what it is supposed to do. Here are a few hints which helped me during this process:

- increase log level to ALL via  config parameter
- check in browser (e.g. via Firebug) that files of hosted mode like devmode.js and hosted.html are queried
- insert Window.alert("..."); into the onModuleLoad() function to see if GWT code is executed at all
- ensure that your app server is executing the exploded war (e.g., delete packaged WAR file before starting app server)
- after startup of app server, don't call page without GWT codeserver parameter as this already generates some GWT files in the webapp exploded folder, which might conflict with those to be created by GWT hosted mode; take note which files are created and delete them manually
- GWT dev mode seems to be not fully deterministic as I was able to get it running after forced reloading of the page in my browser
- start from a working example, e.g. like the one I shared here: https://github.com/steinsag/gwt-maven-example